# App crashes when replacing fragments by button click

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have to replace one fragment with another, I wrote usual code to do so but I have crash.

My code to replace fragments:

```
button1.setOnClickListener {
   supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
         .replace(R.id.content_frame, SecondFragment())
         .commit()
}
button2.setOnClickListener {
   supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
          .replace(R.id.content_frame, FirstFragment())
          .commit()
}
```

Here is my crash:

```
Process: ru.aspirity.stolbyapp.dev, PID: 28475
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-1
    at android.view.ViewGroup.getAndVerifyPreorderedView(ViewGroup.java:3554)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.gatherTransparentRegion(ViewGroup.java:6905)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.gatherTransparentRegion(ViewGroup.java:6907)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.gatherTransparentRegion(ViewGroup.java:6907)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.gatherTransparentRegion(ViewGroup.java:6907)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.gatherTransparentRegion(ViewGroup.java:6907)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.gatherTransparentRegion(ViewGroup.java:6907)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.gatherTransparentRegion(ViewGroup.java:6907)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.gatherTransparentRegion(ViewGroup.java:6907)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.gatherTransparentRegion(DecorView.java:301)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2225)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1392)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6752)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

I also have tried to make add instead of replace, it worked but not correctly for me.

Comment: Are you using any arrays in your fragments? post your fragment code

Comment: Please post the methods: `FirstFragment()` and `SecondFragment()`.

Comment: Could you please post full code? so that it is easy for us to track the crash. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Try something like this:**

> **In your button clicks:**

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                replaceFragment(new SecondFragment());
            }
        });
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                replaceFragment(new FirstFragment());
            }
        });
```

> **// Method to push fragment and maintaining backstack**

```
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        boolean fragmentPopped = manager.popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, 0);

        if (!fragmentPopped && manager.findFragmentByTag(backStateName) == null) {
            //if fragment not in  back stack, create it.
            FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, backStateName);
            ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }
```